# Issue with uploading Arduino sketch on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, uploading, avrdude, ubuntu

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload an Arduino sketch on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. Despite ensuring that the correct board is selected and the USB port is recognized properly, I consistently encounter the following error message:

```
Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I have tried various troubleshooting steps, including changing the board, reinstalling the IDE, and resetting the settings, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Arduino model do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problem, holding down reset on the board until uploading starts often works